# Transform byte array into upside down array of floating point pixels

Tags: python, performance, image, serialization, coordinate-system

I need to do the following in Python 3.x:

1. Interpret an array of bytes as an array of single-precision floats.
2. Then group each four consecutive floats into subarrays, i.e. transform `[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h]` into `[[a,b,c,d], [e,f,g,h]]`. The subarrays are called pixels, and the array of pixels forms an image.
3. Flip the image vertically.

Here is what I have now:

```
floats = array.array('f')
floats.fromstring(tile_data)
pix = []
for y in range(tile_h - 1, -1, -1):
    stride = tile_w * 4
    start_index = y * stride
    end_index = start_index + stride
    pix.extend(floats[i:i + 4] for i in range(start_index, end_index, 4))
```

`tile_data` is the input array of raw bytes, `tile_w` and `tile_h` are respectively the width and height of the image, `pix` is the final upside down image.

While this code works correctly, it takes around 50 ms to complete on my machine for a 256x256 image.

Is there anything obviously slow in this code? Would numpy be a potentially good avenue for optimization?

---

Edit: here is a standalone program to run the code and measure performance:

```
import array
import random
import struct
import time

# Size of the problem.
tile_w = 256
tile_h = 256

# Generate input data.
tile_data = []
for f in (random.uniform(0.0, 1.0) for _ in range(tile_w * tile_h * 4)):
    tile_data.extend(struct.pack("f", f))
tile_data = bytes(tile_data)

start_time = time.time()

# Code of interest.
floats = array.array('f')
floats.fromstring(tile_data)
pix = []
for y in range(tile_h - 1, -1, -1):
    stride = tile_w * 4
    start_index = y * stride
    end_index = start_index + stride
    pix.extend(floats[i:i + 4] for i in range(start_index, end_index, 4))

print("runtime: {0} ms".format((time.time() - start_time) * 1000))
```

Answer (score 1):

> Would numpy be a potentially good avenue for optimization?

Yes. In general, pushing python loops into C extensions often makes sense.

You might prefer to start the timer after `pix = []`, since you're not focused on improving `fromstring`'s performance.

There's nothing obviously slow, beyond bulk data movement and regrouping, and it would take changing the problem if you wanted to introduce a level of indirection to avoid that work. One could hoist the `stride` constant out of the loop, but that's pretty far down the list of worries.

Comment: Thanks for your input! Regarding "you're not focused on improving fromstring's performance", yes I actually am. Basically I'm reading pixel data from a child process' stdout so I need the bytes->floats conversion. Turns out it insignicant compared to the loop below. As expected, hoisting `stride` out of the loop has no measurable incidence. Thanks again!